# How to list all files in current directory whose second character is a digit?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

I tried `ls ?[0-9]*` ,  this matches all files in current directory, but also expands any directories in my current directory as  and matches the files in any sub directory. I want * to match only to current directory.

```
---- Program output --------------------------------
f1
f2
g2t
g3t

d2:

d4:

--- Expected output (text)---
d2
d4
f1
f2
g2t
g3t
```

Here d2 and d4 are directories, while others are files. I want them to be listed as d2 and d4 and not as d2: and d4:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?[0-9]*` *only* expands to names in the *current* directory that has a digit as their second character.  `ls`, when getting a directory name, will obviously show the contents of that directory, which means that you will have to tell `ls` to not not do that.

You do this with `ls -d`:

```
ls -d -- ?[0-9]*
```

or

```
ls -d ./?[0-9]*
```

The `--` and `./` will stop `ls` from interpreting the first character of the filename as an option if it starts with a dash.

If you are only interested in non-directories (and want to also weed out symbolic links to directories), then there are two immediately obvious ways of doing this.

1. Use a shell loop, testing each name to see whether it's a directory or not and display the name if it isn't:

   ```
   for name in ?[0-9]*; do
       [ ! -d "$name" ] && printf '%s\n' "$name"
   done
   ```

   To include files that start with a dot (hidden files), a shell may have a `dotglob` shell option that you may set before the loop (`shopt -s dotglob` in `bash`).
2. Use `find` to look for non-directories (and weed out symbolic links to directories) in the current directory:

   ```
   find -L . -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -name '?[0-9]*'
   ```

   The `-L` option to `find` makes `-type d` refer to the target of any symbolic link (if the current pathname is a symbolic link).

Comment: Beware that on many systems and in some locales, `[0-9]` matches on much more than 0123456789. `[[:digit:]]` should be OK, use `[0123456789]` to be sure.

Comment: Beware that in most Bourne-like shells, if there's no matching file, you may end up listing the `?[0-9]*` file whose second character is not a digit. That's a misfeature introduced by the Bourne shell, fixed again in zsh, or in bash with the failglob option.

Answer (score -1):

You could pipe ls to egrep using a regex like so:

```
ls | egrep '.\d.*'
```

Comment: Can it be done by only using ls and wildcards ?

Comment: Sure you could do this: `ls -d1 ?[0-9]*`

Comment: -1 Don't [pipe ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/18887), especially when `ls -d` is perfectly correct here.